# How to update row values and children when row of outline view is expanded each time it is clicked

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am new in objective c. And I have been looking for examples/answer that describes the outline view expansion of items. Now what I am trying to do is, mark all items as expandable. Now when the user clicks to expand the item, it calls the API, inserts its children if any, and then reload the table view. The Code is given below:

```
 - (BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView isItemExpandable:(id)item{
//initially make all items expandable to check and load data later on
            return YES;
    }

- (NSInteger)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView numberOfChildrenOfItem:(id)item{    
    if (item == nil) {     
        return RootLists.count;
    }
    if ([item isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        reloadCheck=true;
        return [[item objectForKey:@"children"] count];
    }
    return 0;
}

- (id)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView child:(NSInteger)index ofItem:(id)item{

    if (item == nil){       
        return [RootLists objectAtIndex:index];
    }
    if ([item isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        return [[item objectForKey:@"children"] objectAtIndex:index];
    }
    return nil;
}


-(NSView *)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn item:(id)item{
    NSView *rowView;
    rowView=[[NSView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 0, 0)];
    [rowView setWantsLayer:YES];   
     NSTextField *textField;        
    [textField setMaximumNumberOfLines:1];
    [textField setStringValue:[item valueForKey:@"Name"]];       
    [textField setBezeled:NO];
    [textField setDrawsBackground:NO];
    [textField setEditable:NO];
    [textField setSelectable:NO];  
    [rowView addSubview:textField];
    return rowView;
}



    - (BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView  shouldExpandItem:(id)item{
                NSMutableArray *getchildrenlist=[database GetData:[item valueForKey:@"id"]];    
                if (getchildrenlist.count>0) {
//If children are already present then return 1
        return 1;
                }
                else
                {
//If children are not present then hit API, get children online and then reload the view with children
                    dispatch_group_t DispatchGroup = dispatch_group_create();
                    dispatch_group_enter(DispatchGroup);
                    [self ExpandDataApi:1 FolderId:[item valueForKey:@"id"] DispatchGroup:DispatchGroup];              
                    dispatch_group_notify(DispatchGroup,dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
                                [self reloadData:item];
                                [self->_Outline_View reloadData];
    });
        return 1;
                }

            }
```

Now the issue is: the table reloads after each click, but never expands it with new children added to the row. Instead, it collapses all items. But after it is clicked again (same item clicked twice), the item expands correctly with new children.
What I want is: reload table and expand that row with its new children after getting new values.

Comment: If you don't want to restart with collapsed items then don't call `reloadData`. You can expand that row with `expandItem:`.

Comment: i believe reloadData refreshes the table. If i just use expanditem, it will only expand item and not add up new items to the row. i need to either reload that specific row or item but i dont know how to do that.

Comment: You can reload a specific row with `reloadItem:` or `reloadItem:reloadChildren:`. See [NSOutlineView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsoutlineview?language=objc).

Comment: Tried using reloaditem: , but it doesn't reload the children. It will only expand item and not add up new items to the row. I dont know where i am doing wrong in this.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue and it looks like `NSOutlineView` is caching the items and gets out of sync.

Comment: A test app with `NSTreeController` and bindings seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to add  items to view by following code

```
[self->_Outline_View insertItemsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:row] inParent:item withAnimation:NSTableViewAnimationSlideDown];
```

and remove item from row by code:

```
  [self->_Outline_View removeItemsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:row] inParent:item withAnimation:NSTableViewAnimationSlideDown];
```

and then refresh it by using code:

```
[self->_Outline_View reloadItem:item];
  [self->_Outline_View expandItem:item];
```